# Exact behaviour of == and === operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

While writing simple snippet for comparison in JavaScript I observed some weird behavior.

Case 1:

```
typeof(window.WHTStatement.DDL_TPTypeID.size()) ==> "number"
typeof(window.WHTStatement.Txt_TPTypeValue.size()) ==> "number"

window.WHTStatement.DDL_TPTypeID.size() == 1 == window.WHTStatement.Txt_TPTypeValue.size()
```

returns true -- OK

---

Case 2:

```
window.WHTStatement.DDL_TPTypeID.size() === 1 == window.WHTStatement.Txt_TPTypeValue.size()
```

returns true -- OK

---

Case 3:

```
window.WHTStatement.DDL_TPTypeID.size() === 1 === window.WHTStatement.Txt_TPTypeValue.size()
```

returns false, why?

What exactly happening here in case 3. Can somebody elaborate?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use/359509#359509

Comment: It's not "weird" behaviour; there is a difference between "weird" behaviour and behaviour which you -- not anyone else, though! -- did not expect.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike Python, in JS `x == y == z` is not equal to `x == y && y == z` but `(x == y) == z`. So you are actually comparing a boolean to a number which obviously fails in a type check.

The `==` comparison worked because `1 == true` is `true`.